# How can make dynamic time action button

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on phonegap with android. i want to create multiple buttons at run time.

This is the function which get a list of url. So want to create a list of buttons one for each  url. so whenever i press that button then i can reach to that url.'

Number of buttons depends on the number of url get by this function. Please suggest me what should i do for this to create button at run time.

this the code which are getting URLs:-

```
function getData(){
   var output = $('#rt');
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://192.168.1.214/MusicApplication/searchlatest.php',
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
         timeout: 5000,
         success: function(data, status){
             if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)){
                 alert("invalid user");
             }else{

                 $.each(data, function(i,item){
                 alert(item.url);
                 //what should i do to create number of buttons according to each URL which 
                 //are received from php page(a server page)
                 output.append(logi);
             });
             }
         },
         error: function(){

            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your Parent layout's id is linearLayout.

Use an ArrayList and you could add each button dynamically and have each button with it's own onclicklistener.

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfURLS; i++){
     buttonList.ensureCapacity(buttonList.size()+1);
     buttonList.add(new Button(this));
     buttonList.get(i).setText("Text Here");
     buttonList.get(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                         openURL(URL); //Here, I'm assuming you made your own method with an intent or whatever to open the desired url.    
                    }
                });
}
```

Comment if you need more clarification or information. I'd be glad to help.